# How to pass RawWindowHandle::Windows to winapi::winuser::SetWindowPos

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm trying to make a window I created using the `winit` crate be always on top (`HWND_TOPMOST`). I'm creating my window, and getting the `RawWindowHandle::Windows` from it. That [struct](https://docs.rs/raw-window-handle/0.3.3/raw_window_handle/windows/struct.WindowsHandle.html) has a `pub hwnd` which is a `*mut c_void`. And my question now is, how can I convert that `*mut c_void` to a `*mut winapi::shared::windef::HWND__` so I can pass it to `winapi::winuser::SetWindowPos(...)`?

Here's my code for getting the raw window handle:

```rust
let win_handle = match window.raw_window_handle() {
    RawWindowHandle::Windows(windows_handle) => windows_handle.hwnd,
    _ => panic!("Unsupported platform!"),
};
```

And this is my code passing `win_handle` to `SetWindowPos`:

```rust
unsafe {
    if winuser::SetWindowPos(win_handle, winuser::HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, winuser::SWP_NOMOVE | winuser::SWP_NOSIZE) == 1 {
        println!("Success");
    } else {
        println!("Failure");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simpler solution yet: Let Rust figure out the type. In your call to `SetWindowPos` simply pass `win_handle as _`. Though keep in mind: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: @IInspectable ah, that works too. Thanks for the tip, although I solved my problem the easy way (letting winit handle it for me), but I'll remember that whenever I need to cast something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is a [HWND struct](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/shared/windef/type.HWND.html) to which you can simply cast the `*mut c_void`, like so:

```rust
let winapi_handle = win_handle as winuser::shared::windef::HWND;

// Or even simple, cast it in the call with 'as _'
// Shoutout to @IInspectable
SetWindowPos(win_handle as _, winuser::HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, winuser::SWP_NOMOVE | winuser::SWP_NOSIZE)
```

**Edit:** It was only after I tried this that I actually googled "Winit set window always on top" and found [this](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/pull/528). So, when constructing your window using a `WindowBuilder` you can simply call

```rust
window_builder.with_always_on_top(true)
```

And it will do it for you on all supported platforms (Linux, Windows and MacOS. Adnroid, iOS and the Web do not support it)